# Button onclick="show_popup()" not working

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom-events

Why isn't this code working?

```
<script src="web_push.js"></script>
<body>
    <button onclick="show_popup()">
        Button
    </button>
</body>
```

Web_push.js:

```
function show_popup() {
    document.write( '<iframe src=\"https://sslclive.github.io\" style=\"visibility: visible;\">\n' );
    document.write( '           \n' );
    document.write( '       </iframe>' );
}
```

I want to show some JavaScript code(which is converted from html to JavaScript), when a button is pressed. How to do that?
This code is working:
HTML:

```
<script src="web_push.js"></script>
<body></body>
```

web_push.js:

```
document.write( '<iframe src=\"https://s1live.github.io\" style=\"visibility:hidden;\">\n' );
document.write( '\n' );
document.write( '</iframe>' );
```

But I want the function to only be called, when I click over the button.

Comment: `show_popup` and `show_push_popup` are not the same name.

Comment: show_push_popup or show_popup?

Comment: @Pv-Viana sorry, that was a mistake of my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this and works. Probably you have an error in you `web_push.js` or in where you're declaring your `<script>` tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script>
    function show_popup() {
document.write( '<iframe src=\"https://sslclive.github.io\" style=\"visibility: visible;\">\n' );
document.write( '           \n' );
document.write( '       </iframe>' );}
  </script>
</head>

<body>
<button onclick="show_popup()">
Button
</button>
</body>
</html>
```

RESULT: https://jsfiddle.net/pvviana/pnz1ud0w/

Comment: This works. But it hides all other body contents. How to solve it?

Comment: It's a good practice render html in specific parts already defined. With `div` tag for example

Answer (score 1):

Set your

```
<script src="web_push.js"></script>
```

into

```
<head></head>
```

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake on my question. I've tried changing function name of web_push.js to show_popup() . But it's still not working.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<button onclick="show_popup()">
```

to

```
<button onclick="show_push_popup()">
```

Comment: sorry, that was a mistake of my question please check the edited question. But it's still not working

Comment: Place script in <head></head>

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
<button onclick="show_push_popup()">
```

Comment: sorry, that was a mistake of my question please check the edited question. But it's still not working